# Is anybody else experiencing disappearing source files when using Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, git

I've been having a weird problem on a MacBook Pro; My source files disappear. It can happen when the files are not open in any application (although they are *referenced* by active projects in Xcode and the compilers are reading them…). I can start a long build, walk away, and along the way the compiler complains that it cannot find an `#include` at some point in the build (the file's disappeared at that point). I then revert from git history. Fortunately, I've not lost any data (yet!), but it's quite an annoying issue. I do use git clients (specifically, SmartGit and SourceTree), but the problem appears unrelated to these clients because I can work with either for extended periods and the problem still arises. As far as I know, other files have not been disappearing from this machine, but I use it almost exclusively for development. And maybe it's not at all related to Xcode…

**Has anybody else had a similar problem, or is this a confirmed issue? …and is there a solution?**

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue.  At first I thought it was me doing something wrong, then it hit me again last night.

I am using a corporate macbook pro I7 (which seems to run slower than my personal 2009 macbook core-2 duo, but i regress...)  I was vpn'd into work with Cisco Any connect.

I got to a stopping point, went to commit the files, added my comment and before I hit the commit button, I lost the vpn.  No problem I thought as the commit is only to the local repository, but when I hit commit, I got an error saying this is not a git repository.  I flipped back to my project and half the files were gone.  Luckily the 4 files I had been working in were still there, but I had another project open at the same time, and I lost everything there but the project file.  Luckily I had pushed to our git server twice that day, but did lose a little work.

The computer is running McAffee AV.

I'm wondering if it's something to do with the mobile account on the mac.

None of the source code files are in the trash, they just vanish.

I'm storing my projects in ~/Projects/Mobile/Project1... but I have also lost source code in ~/Documents/Projects before.

Zip files in the ~/Projects/Mobile folder are unaffected.
All source code files in MOST all project folders disappear, even projects that were not open in XCode.